# How to change thickness of Dynamic Lines?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently using dynamic lines for application, but the lines created are too thin and I'd like to make it thicker. How could I do that?

If not possible, could someone point an alternative?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21489/how-to-change-thickness-of-dynamic-lines?/) by [rasecg3](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7335/rasecg3/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ogre, the rendering engine used by Gazebo, [only supports 1px wide lines](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1978/its-not-possible-to-change-rendering-grids). An alternative would be to use billboards, or very thin cylinders.

You can find an example of billboards being used on Gazebo's source code on the model editor's [JointMaker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/29a9761d43c5c2f9364cceb5fdc1abf8b93d29e8/gazebo/gui/model/JointMaker.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#JointMaker.cc-818) for example. In this case, the billboards are the squares which get attached to both ends of the joint line.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rasecg3](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7335/rasecg3/) on 2018-12-19**:
Humm, thank you!  What would be "billboards"?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-12-19**:
updated the question pointing to some billboard code.

**Comment by [rasecg3](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7335/rasecg3/) on 2018-12-20**:
It worked, thanks! I actually used Billboard Chains. The problem I have now it that the lines are being detected by my GPU laser. Is there a way remove the lines obstruction, but make it still visible by the cameras?

**Comment by [rasecg3](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7335/rasecg3/) on 2018-12-20**:
I managed by doing the following:
1 - created a specific mask for the billboard, i.e, GZ_VISIBILITY_BILLBOARD

2 - billboard->setVisibilityMask(GZ_VISIBILITY_BILLBOARD)

3 - changed GPULaser 1st and 2nd viewports to:  (GZ_VISIBILITY_ALL & ~(GZ_VISIBILITY_GUI | GZ_VISIBILITY_SELECTABLE | GZ_VISIBILITY_BILLBOARD))

4 - recompiled gazebo source code.

The question is...is there a way to do it without changing gazebo source code? Form model plugin I think 1st and 2nd viewport are not accessible.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-12-20**:
You should be able to use `GZ_VISIBILITY_GUI` instead of the new mask you created.

**Comment by [mogumbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6355/mogumbo/) on 2019-01-03**:
RViz also uses billboard lines. I've wondered why they do this instead of using GL_LINES of a specific pixel size. This could be because I'm an old graphics curmudgeon and "lines" makes me think of GL_LINES. I suppose there are good uses for both styles.